# Can't change an asp page because of a required validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

On one of my asp.net pages I have a few textboxes and a required validator attached to them. Everything is ok with validation, but when I want to change page to another required validator doesn't allow it because I don't fill in a textbox :/

How to allowed change page without fill a validate textbox? I must create a condition in "exit page" (how is it named ?) event disabled required validation?

Please help ;)

Comment: Good question. Although english could be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using some control to move to the next page, set it's `CausesValidation` property to `False`.

For example, if you're clicking a button that moves you to the next page, it would be like:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="myButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" .... />
```